# Finding value of the summation

Tags: summation

How can I solve the following summation for a set $S$?

$$\sum\limits_{s \subset S} \left[\max(s)-\min(s)\right]$$

Example :

If $S = \{1,5,2\}$

Subset $= \{1\}$, $\max(s)-\min(s) = 0$.

Subset $= \{5\}$, $\max(s)-\min(s) = 0$.

Subset $= \{2\}$, $\max(s)-\min(s) = 0$.

Subset $= \{1,5\}$, $\max(s)-\min(s) = 4$.

Subset $= \{5,2\}$, $\max(s)-\min(s) = 3$.

Subset $= \{1,2\}$, $\max(s)-\min(s) = 1$.

Subset $= \{1,5,2\}$, $\max(s)-\min(s) = 4$.

So the Result will be $0+0+0+4+3+1+4 = 12$.

**Please Note** : for a set $\{1,2,2\}$, subsets are $\{1\},\{2\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,2\}$.

Comment: $\{1, 2, 2\}$ is a multi-set (not a set)... do we know anything about $S$? or is is just generic (multi)-set?

Comment: Its just a multi-set. There isn't any other speciality .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you order the $n$ elements of $S$ as $a_1<a_2<\ldots <a_n$, then $a_k$ is the maximal element of precisely $2^{k-1}$ subsets and is the minimal element of precisely $2^{n-k}$ subsets. Therefore 
$$\sum_{\emptyset\ne s\subseteq S}(\max s-\min s)=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\cdot(2^{k-1}-2^{n-k})= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k(a_{k+1}-a_{n-k}). $$
The above remains correct if one allows multisets (i.e., the $a_i$ are ordered only by $\le$, not $<$).

Comment: The set may not contain consecutive numbers. I have edited the question. Please reconsider. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @user2399614 There is no need to reconsider